# Enter chinese filename in Windows command prompt window

Tags: windows, command-prompt, livecode, md5sum

How to enter in chinese filename in Windows command prompt window?

Suppose you have a filename 公司File.txt somewhere.
And you want to execute the md5sum.exe program on that file.

```
md5sum.exe 公司File.txt
```

You will get...

```
md5sum.exe: ??File.txt: Invalid argument
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
chcp 1201
```

in the command prompt, if you have installed the Chinese language pack. You could also try 65001, but apparently this is not compatible with your Chinese file name.